# replace function does not work in dynamic sql query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

I am facing an problem in replacing the character in sql query. I am using vs 2008. I am trying to replace the Turkish character İ to I.

Works fine:

```
Select FirstName, REPLACE(FirstName,N'İ','I') replaced 
from Employee where FirstName = N'İAİL'
```

Fails when used as dynamic statement.

Same query fails to replace in  dynamic statement.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @SQL = 'Select FirstName, REPLACE(FirstName,N''İ'',''I'') replaced from Employee where FirstName = N'İAİL'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Can you let me know why this fails in second condition?

Answer (score 2):

Copying and pasting into SSMS the syntax highlighting showed you're missing some apostrophes on the end of your statement:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @SQL = 'Select FirstName, REPLACE(FirstName,N''İ'',''I'') replaced from Employee where FirstName = N''İAİL'''
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Dynamic SQL like that with lots of strings is a royal PITA.